# Hermitian matrix has positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

I understand that Hermitian matrices has real eigenvalues.

Just to hit the point home, I have the following question.

Does every Hermitian matrix have eigenvalues? Since the proof assumes that the eigenvalue exists, the proof does not imply that every Hermitian matrix must have some eigenvalues. It just says that if it has an eigenvalue, then the eigenvalue must be real.

Comment: Every complex matrix has at least one eigenvalue

Comment: This is because every characteristic polynomial has at least one root

Comment: great! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Title question seems different from question in body.

Comment: @BenGrossmann There is exactly one finite square complex matrix that has no eigenvalue. I'll leave it as a puzzle to find out which one.

Comment: @Marc Interesting to get a response on such an old question. Could you be referring to the $0 \times 0$ matrix?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, thanks to the robot that is randomly pushing old questions to the front. And indeed, that's the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Every complex $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix (or real symmetric matrix) has $n$ real eigenvalues. However, these eigenvalues might not be distinct. As a trivial example, 
$$
B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
         5 & 0 & 0 \\
         0  & 5 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 1
      \end{array} \right)
$$ 
has three eigenvalues but two of them are equal.

For any Hermitian matrix $A$, there exists a complex matrix $U$ such that $U^tU = I$, (where $I$ the identity matrix) and
$$
U^tAU = \Lambda
$$
where $\Lambda$ is a real diagonal matrix which contains the eigenvalues of $A$. If $A$ is real symmetric then the matrix $U$ is real. The $k$th diagonal element of $\Lambda$ is the $k$th eigenvalue and it corresponds to the $k$th eigenvector given by the $k$th column of $U$.

Alternatively, $A$ can be written as
$$
A = U \Lambda U^t 
$$ 
which is often known as the spectral decomposition of $A$.